# Kafka Streams - GroupBy - Late Event - persistentWindowStore - WindowBy with Grace Period and Suppress

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My purpose to calculate success and fail message from source to destination per second and sum their results in daily bases.

I had two options to do that ;

1. stream events then group them time#source#destination

```
KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier streamStore = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("store-name");  
sourceStream.selectKey((k, v) -> v.getDataTime() + KEY_SEPERATOR + SRC + KEY_SEPERATOR + DEST ).groupByKey().aggregate(
DO SOME Aggregation,
    Materialized.<String, AggregationObject>as(streamStore)
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(AggregationObjectSerdes));
```

After trying this approach above  we noticed that state store is getting increase because of number of unique keys are increasing and if i am correct, because of state topics are only "compact" they are never expires.

> NumberOfUniqueKeys = 86.400 seconds in a day X SOURCE X DESTINATION

**Then** we thought that if we do not put a time field in a KEY block, we can reduce state store size. We tried windowing operation as second approach.

2. using windowing operation with persistentWindowStore, CustomTimeStampExtractor, WindowBy, Suppress

```
WindowBytesStoreSupplier streamStore = Stores.persistentWindowStore("store-name", Duration.ofHours(6), Duration.ofSeconds(1), false);

sourceStream.selectKey((k, v) -> SRC + KEY_SEPERATOR + DEST)
.groupByKey()  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(5)))
.aggregate(
    {
       DO SOME Aggregation
    }, Materialized.<String, AggregationObject>as(streamStore)
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
        .withValueSerde(AggregationObjectSerdes))
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded())).toStream();`
```

After trying that second approach, we reduced state store size but now we had problem with late arrive events. Then we added grace period with 5 seconds with suppress operation and in addition using grace period and suppress operation did not guarantee to handle all late arrived events, another side effect of suppress operation is a latency because it emits result of aggregation after window grace period.

**BTW**

using windowing operation caused a getting WARNING message like 
"WARN 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.state.internals.WindowKeySchema  : Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX"

I checked the reason from source code and I found from here 
https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/WindowKeySchema.java

```
/**
 * Safely construct a time window of the given size,
 * taking care of bounding endMs to Long.MAX_VALUE if necessary
 */
static TimeWindow timeWindowForSize(final long startMs,
                                    final long windowSize) {
    long endMs = startMs + windowSize;

    if (endMs < 0) {
        LOG.warn("Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX");
        endMs = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return new TimeWindow(startMs, endMs);
}
```

**BUT** actually it does not make any sense to me that how endMs can be lower than 0...

Questions ?

1. What if we go through with approach 1, how can we reduce state store size ? In approach 1, It was guaranteed that all event will be processed and there will be no missing event because of latency.
2. What if we go through with approach 2, how should i tune my logic and catch late arrival data and reduce latency ?
3. Why do i get Warning message in approach 2 although all time fields are positive in my model ?
4. What can be other options that you can suggest other then these two approaches ?

I need some expert help :)

BR,

Answer (score 0):

According to mail kafka mail group about warning message

WARNING message like "WARN 1 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.state.internals.WindowKeySchema : Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX"

It was written to me :

You can get this message "o.a.k.s.state.internals.WindowKeySchema :
Warning: window end time was truncated to Long.MAX"" when your
TimeWindowDeserializer is created without a windowSize. There are two
constructors for a TimeWindowDeserializer, are you using the one with
WindowSize?

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedDeserializer.java#L46-L55

It calls WindowKeySchema with a Long.MAX_VALUE
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedDeserializer.java#L84-L90